# How move focus from button on form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two buttons, Connect and Disconnect. When I launch the Connect only form is enabled. As soon as I press disability and enables Disconnect. How can I pass the focus to the form that contains them?

Comment: Reading this, I very little idea what is happening in your application, and I have even less idea what you want to have happen. Please explain much more clearly. I can't even parse the sentences you've written.

Comment: I have the focus on a button. I have to return the focus to the form to manage keyboard commands ..

Comment: Please replace the text of your question with a clear statement of what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Forms don't take Focus. You can enabled the `Form.KeyPreview` and subscribe to the `PreviewKeyPress` event or you can override `ProcessCmdKey` (no need to set the `KeyPreview` property). This allows to process key presses no matter where the Focus is when the event is generated. Of course, if `Space` is pressed while, for example, the Focus is on a Button, the code in the `Button.Click` handler will be run (as the TextChanged event of a TextBox). You can suppress specific keys, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call:

```
yourButtonName.Focus();
```

or

```
yourButtonName.Select();
```